# Display camera preview on a circular surface (porthole effect)

Tags: android

I want to display the camera preview onto a circular surface (similar to a porthole view). I would also need the area surrounding the preview to be empty (transparent), so I believe masking would not help.

I've tried creating a drawable shape and then setting it as the background of a SurfaceView but it doesn't work.

Any ideas if it can be done and how?

Answer (score 2):

If you check out [SurfaceView](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/SurfaceView.java), `draw` and `dispatchDraw` (starts at line 344) make a square "porthole" to show the content. What you can do is make a class that extends `SurfaceView` and override these, the way they do, using a circle path instead:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
canvas.drawPath(circ, paint);
```

`circ` is created as a `Path`. For example:

```java
Path circ = new Path();
circ.addCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getWidth() / 2, Path.Direction.CW);
```

Also, you need to make sure that you set the z order to the top:

```java
this.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

Comment: it works for Activiy. But if I try to add the CameraPreview to WindowManager of Service, I didn't get the circle.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved it by extending the surface view and override:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    clipPath = new Path();
    //TODO: define the circle you actually want
    clipPath.addCircle((float) dpToPx(100), (float) dpToPx(100), (float) dpToPx(100), Path.Direction.CW);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

    canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
    canvas.drawPath(clipPath, paint);
   this.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```